# How can I visualize the center of mass (center of momentum) frame?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, reference-frames, relative-motion

I know that the CM frame is the frame in which the total momentum of the system adds up to zero.

For example, if I imagine two bodies **m1** and **m2**, with **m1 = m2**, one moving at the speed **v1 = v** and the other standing at **v2 = 0**, we can say that in the CM frame they are both moving at the speed of **|v*| = |v/2|**.

How can I mentally visualize the position of the observer that sees both bodies moving at that speed? I think the observer should move at a certain speed too, but which speed?

Comment: I wrote a [Newtonian Gravity simulator](http://www3.sympatico.ca/michael.enns/) which has an option to observe in the centre of mass frame of reference.  Maybe that will help you wizualize...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't it just v/2 in the direction of the resting body?
The observer will see the resting mass approaching him/her at v/2 from the front and the moving body approaching at v/2 from the back.

Comment: I think that traveling at that speed would be too slow in the Laboratory frame and would put the observer onto the body m1 within the CM frame. Am I wrong? Maybe **v/4**?

Answer (score 1):

Visualize the point half way between m1 and m2. Since m1=m2 that is where the CM always is. As V.F. said, it moves with speed v/2.

Comment: Very useful clarification